# Non_exist relationships displayed in LInux Neo4j (version3.5)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

HI i am using a aws ec2 to run a neo4j server. Before that I test in my local machine (Mac OS). everything works fine. But when I uploaded the same graph.db to ec2 and call db.schema(), there are some non-exists relationships. I acknowledge these relationships exist in my old graph.db. but I already deleted the whole graph.db file before load again. So I am wondering there are may be cached by neo4j? I run some queries for the relationships, there are do have some nodes show up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-standing [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9726) that has was reported in version 3.2.2 and still apparently exists in 4.0.0.

Comment: I don't think it is because of the reported issue. In the issue, call apoc.meta.graph will give the correct answer. But in my case, call apoc.meta.graph and db.schema will give the same wrong answer. Also, in the issue it seems all non-exist relaitons do exist in the db. But in my case, the relationship didn't event exist in the new db. It just exists in the old db which I have deleted.